# What is the difference between a quantum turing machine and a non-deterministic turing machine?

Tags: turing-machines, quantum-computation

(first of all, is this the right stackexchange forum to ask this question?)

A non-deterministic turing machine, if I understand it correctly, can have an if statement and then go to two different instructions and run them simultaneously.

If I understand it correctly, this can cause a N-D Turing machine to branch out and create a potentially exponentially growing number of "threads" that all perform different calculations. This allows it to reduce the time it takes to **find** a solution to a problem X, to the time it takes to **check** a solution to the problem X.

Isn't that how a quantum computer works?

Comment: Why would that matter? Turing machines are purely mathematical objects anyway. That said, if you imagined implementing such a Turing machine (with bounds on memory and thread count, of course), the idea there is separate threads processing each branch of the decision tree.

Comment: (Cont.) A quantum computer is not doing that; it is performing quantum manipulations to the quantum superposition of the branches of the tree. The trick is to set up the quantum manipulations so that they *behave* like separately acting on the separate threads, to give the familiar exponential speedup. This turns out to not work in general. Only certain kinds of parallel manipulations can be achieved this way.

Comment: (Cont.) This is why so many of the known quantum algorithms proceed by reducing the problem to something that we know can be done efficiently by a quantum computer, such as the quantum Fourier transform.